# How to add click listener to a keyboard button enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, onclicklistener

I have created a javascript code but the function of clicking on the enter button does not work yet, how can it work?

html

```
<div class="landing-pages-form-search">
     <input type="text" name="search" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
     <input type="submit" onclick="return landingSearch();">
</div>
```

javascript

```
    function landingSearch() {
        let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('landing-pages-column');

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
                $("#load-more").hide();
            }
            else {
                x[i].style.display = "list-item";
                $("#load-more").hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

please help me, where can i add the code click listener?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? Do you want to submit the form with the enter key?

Comment: yass, i want to submit with enter key :(

Comment: $('#searchbar').keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            landingSearch();
        }
    });

Comment: Put the `input` and `button` inside a `form` and set the action of the form to the page you want to submit the data to. Then hook your JS to the `submit` event of that form

Comment: `$('#searchbar').on("keydown", function(event) { if (event.keyCode == 13) { } });`

Comment: this inputs should be inside of a form

Comment: form is not important, he is getting input by id

Comment: @AhmedSunny the form is very important, that's what makes the return key submission work without needing to add a key handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use inputs inside a form and set your handler on the submit event and it will work for click and enter

```js
const form = document.getElementsByClassName('landing-pages-form-search')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', landingSearch);
function landingSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('enter works');
        let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('landing-pages-column');

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
                $("#load-more").hide();
            }
            else {
                x[i].style.display = "list-item";
                $("#load-more").hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="landing-pages-form-search">
     <input type="text" name="search" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
<div class="landing-pages-column">1</div>
<div class="landing-pages-column">2</div>
<div class="landing-pages-column">3</div>
<div class="landing-pages-column">4</div>
<div class="landing-pages-column">5</div>
```

Comment: i try this code but the result is back to first condition, like i have 5 content and i try to search content 2, when i click enter the result show 2 and suddenly back to first condition 5 content

Comment: @Dini when you type 2 and press enter, should be visible only second item?

Comment: yaa, try to access mylink and seacrh hull or seiko

Comment: type 2 is example for my answer before

Comment: @Dini looks like you didn't add `e` and `e.preventDefault();`, look at my code

Comment: oo i see, bcs off cache, sorry
thankyou very much @ivan its work thankyou again

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add an event listener for the form submission.
You only need to wrap the input fields in a form tag and the enter key will automatically work. like so

```
<form action="">
 <div class="landing-pages-form-search">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return landingSearch();">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i try it but the result is back to initial display

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function and call your other function on the respected event

```
$('#searchbar').keypress(function(event) {  // or keydown
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {  // code for Enter
        landingSearch();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `input` and `button` inside a `form` and set the action of the form to the page you want to submit the data to. Then hook your JS to the `submit` event of that form:

```html
<div class="landing-pages-form-search">
  <form action="#" id="search-form">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
let loadMore = document.querySelector('#load-more');

document.querySelector('#search-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let input = (document.querySelector('#searchbar').value || '').toLowerCase();
  let x = document.querySelector('.landing-pages-column');

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
      loadMore.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display = "list-item";
      loadMore.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
```

Note the use of unobtrusive an event handler in the above example, in place of an outdated `onclick` attribute

Comment: i try this code but the result is back to first condition, like i have 5 content and i try to search content 2, when i click enter the result show 2 and suddenly back to first condition 5 content

Comment: I don't know what you mean, and without seeing a full example including relevant HTML and CSS it's impossible to see the problem